# plot always plots relative to origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to use `plot` to draw a sine somewhere in a picture. I expected the coordinates to be relative to the current coordinate, but they seem to be relative to `(0,0)`. Below is an MWE that does not do what I like together with its resulting figure and the figure I would have expected it to produce. In this simple case it is rather straightforward to add the offset to the plot coordinates. My intended figure is a bit more involved though, so I would like to do this properly. Is there a way to plot an arbitrary function at the current coordinate?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % indicate origin
        \draw [red] (0,0) circle (.03);
        % plot something that works as intended
        \draw [green, domain=0:1] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) -- ++(2,1);
        % this does not plot as intended
        \draw [blue, domain=0:1] (0,0) -- ++(1,-1) plot({-\x},{sin(360*\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround might be to add `coordinate (tmp)` right before `plot`, and add `shift={(tmp)}` to the `plot` options.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % indicate origin
        \draw [red] (0,0) circle (.03);
        % plot something that works as intended
        \draw [green, domain=0:1] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) -- ++(2,1);
        % this plots as intended
        \draw [blue, domain=0:1] (0,0) -- ++(1,-1) coordinate(tmp) plot[shift={(tmp)}] ({-\x},{sin(360*\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the approach with `coordinate (tmp)` does not allow you to continue the path seamlessly. The current path location will be off by the negative `shift` amount. This presents problems when chaining plots together:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red] (0,0) circle (.03);
    \draw [blue, domain=0:1] (0,0) -- ++(1,-1)
        coordinate(tmp) plot[shift=(tmp)] ({\x},{sin(360*\x)})
        coordinate(tmp) plot[shift=(tmp)] ({\x},{\x^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Paths are disconnected]

The blue path should be continuous. You could fix this by adding `++(tmp)` after every plot, but we can also automate the process by defining our own style `relative plot`.

Note that this only works for plots which start at `(0,0)`, like `sin(x)` or `x^2`. The plot for `cos(x)` starts at `(0,1) and is thus offset by 1 cm from the end of the previous plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    relative plot/.style={
        /utils/exec={\xdef\relativePlotLocation{\the\tikz@lastxsaved,\the\tikz@lastysaved}},
        shift=(\relativePlotLocation),
        append after command={++(\relativePlotLocation)},
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red] (0,0) circle (.03); % indicate origin
    \draw [blue, domain=0:1] (0,0) -- ++(1,-1)
        plot[relative plot] ({\x},{sin(360*\x)})
        plot[relative plot] ({\x},{\x^2})
        plot[relative plot] ({\x},{cos(360*\x)})
            node[above left] {\tiny cos does not start at 0,0 :-(}
        -- (0,0); % normal drawing also works
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plots are chained together (except cosine)]